Upload .pfx certificate while using Selenium Chrome WebDriver
I'm currently working on a Python script to interact and scrape a website using Selenium, and the website require a certificate, which I have with my .pfx file and the certificate password. Previously, I would upload the .pfx file manually in Chrome settings (in the Manage Certificate section). However, I wanted to automate the process, and was wondering if there's any way to programmatically pass the .pfx file and the password via Selenium.
Appreciate the help.
I've tried the approach in this thread Chromedriver in Selenium and SSL certificate but every time the program access the website, it couldn't access it.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os
import time

def setup_chrome_with_certificate(cert_path, cert_password):
    chrome_options = Options()

    # Ignore certificate errors
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

    # Set Chrome preferences
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True
    })

    
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)    
    return driver


cert_path = r"C:\Path\to\file.pfx"
cert_password = 'Password'

driver = setup_chrome_with_certificate(cert_path, cert_password)
driver.get("https://website.com")
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
 

